# Versioned deployment in JBoss is possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, web-deployment

Is there any way to deploy a new version of my application and still keep the old one up and running in JBoss. So the running instances will still use the current version and all new instances will be able to invoke the new deployed version of the application.As soon as all the sessions who are using the old version of the application are expired, Application sever will recognize it and will deactivate the old version. So at this moment only the new deployed version is active and all new sessions will make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you can't register two applications under the same context-root (/my-application). A Load-Balancer in front of 2 JBoss-Instances could do the trick.